# RAILS 3RC NoMethodError: undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have following error on Rails 3 RC, I do not understand what was going:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.0.beta4)
>> o = Objekt.new
=> #<Objekt id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, hash: nil, phone: nil, adress: nil,    description: nil, price: nil, lng: nil, lat: nil, klass: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> o.adress = "some adress"
=> "some adress"
>> o.save!
NoMethodError: undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `uniq'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `commit_transaction_records'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:165:in `transaction'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:202:in `transaction'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save!'
from (irb):3
>>
```

Comment: What does your `Objekt` class look like? Do you have some `before_save` blocks or anything like that?

Comment: Nothing spacial:

    class Objekt < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates_presence_of :adress
    end